# Exceljs App "is working on your function" message

Tags: typescript, office-js, exceljs, excel-web-addins

I modified an Excel ScriptLab function to remove duplicates and I run it as a button from the Ribbon.

```
async function RemoveDuplicates() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {    
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var selectedRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    var firstCell = selectedRange.getCell(0, 0);
    var surroundingRegion = selectedRange.getSurroundingRegion();

    firstCell.load('columnIndex');
    surroundingRegion.load('address');

    await context.sync();
    var columnIndex = firstCell.columnIndex;
    
    const deleteResult = surroundingRegion.removeDuplicates([columnIndex], true);
    deleteResult.load();
  });
}
```

It works well. It finished in a fraction of the second, but I noticed that this, and any other function I have, displays in the bottom-right corner a message that stays there until I run another function. And then the message from the next function stays there.

[image]

Is this normal, or should there be a code to end this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to pass an [Office.AddinCommands.Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.addincommands.event?view=common-js) parameter to `removeDuplicates` and then call `event.completed()` at the end of the function. For an example, see [Create add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands) and [FunctionFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile).

Comment: I used the code you suggested and it works. Thank you. But this code is for JS, and TS takes also type.

I tried 
async function highlightNonEnglish(event: Event),

 but it returns error, so I used this code:

async function highlightNonEnglish(event: any).

This works weell. Is this a good way in this case?

Comment: I believe the data type for the parameter is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.addincommands.event?view=common-js

Comment: I added this link to the original answer.